# Accept.js AJAX POST failing for createCustomerProfile endpoint in sandbox

Tags: ajax, authorize.net

I'm able to successfully post to the createCustomerProfile endpoint using ARC, but NOT with a simple AJAX post inside javascript.  I'm using the following AJAX request:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: 'https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api',
            dataType: "json",
            data: createCustomerProfileRequest,
            success: function (response) {
            if (response.dataValue == "Error") {
                alert(response.dataDescriptor);
            } else {
               alert('Successfully sumitted payment!');
            }
                $("#ccButton").attr("disabled", false);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('Could NOT submit payment!');
                $("#ccButton").attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
```

My data is verified to be the following:

```
  "createCustomerProfileRequest": {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
      "name": "myActualApiKey",
      "transactionKey": "myActualTransactionKey"
    },
    "profile": {
      "merchantCustomerId": "Homer Simpson",
      "description": "Creating Customer Profile for: Homer Simpson",
      "email": "crodgers@newbenefits.com",
      "paymentProfiles": {
        "customerType": "individual",
        "payment": {
          "creditCard": {
            "cardNumber": "6011000990139424",//Test credit card
            "expirationDate": "2028-01"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not certain what i'm doing wrong here.  I know i have to have the crossDomain set to true but i keep running into the following parsing error:

```
"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line 0, position 0."
```

What is causing this to happen in the browser (i'm using Chrome) and NOT when using ARC?

Comment: You can get Success result , if you don't use AJAX?

Comment: I always get an HTTP code of 200: Success when posting via AJAX.  However, the error i'm receiving is the response to the 200.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to stringify the JSON i was sending.  This will work:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: 'https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api',
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(createCustomerProfileRequest),
            data: createCustomerProfileRequest,
            success: function (response) {
            if (response.dataValue == "Error") {
                alert(response.dataDescriptor);
            } else {
               alert('Successfully sumitted payment!');
            }
                $("#ccButton").attr("disabled", false);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('Could NOT submit payment!');
                $("#ccButton").attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
```